# Deserialization JAXBElement with jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jaxb, jackson

I have a such model:

```
public class Type {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "ConversationId", namespace = "...", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> conversationId;
}
```

and part of json:

```
  "conversationId": {
    "declaredType": "java.lang.String",
    "globalScope": false,
    ...,
    "value": "ABC000000001"
  },
```

I tried use this mapper for deserialization:

```
public static interface JAXBElementMixin {
    @JsonValue
    Object getValue();
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JaxbAnnotationIntrospector jaxbAnnotationIntrospector=new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(mapper.getTypeFactory());
JacksonAnnotationIntrospector jacksonAnnotationIntrospector=new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(AnnotationIntrospector.pair(jaxbAnnotationIntrospector, jacksonAnnotationIntrospector));

mapper.addMixIn(JAXBElement.class, JAXBElementMixin.class);
```

But in any case, my program doesn't work well I got:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)

I wanted to read some docs about mixins, but there is outdated information on the offcial jackson's website, I use 2.5.1 version

Comment: I have the same problem, found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and finally was able to figure it out. Two things need to happen in order for this to work:

1. The Mixin class MUST be in the separate file, not an inner or
   anonymous class.
2. The Mixin class MUST be in a different package,
   i.e. if the code which creates the mapper is in the package
   `com.foo.bar` then Mixin class MUST NOT be in this package.

Here's my code:

```
package com.foo.bar;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"globalScope", "typeSubstituted", "nil", "scope"})
public abstract class JAXBElementMixIn<T> extends JAXBElement<T> {
    @JsonCreator
    public JAXBElementMixIn(@JsonProperty("name") QName name,
                            @JsonProperty("declaredType") Class<T> declaredType,
                            @JsonProperty("value") T value) {
        super(name, declaredType, value);
    }
}
```

and the code which uses it:

```
package x.y.z;

...

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixIn(JAXBElement.class, JAXBElementMixIn.class);
```